# Ruby Enumerator using callcc doesn't terminate

Tags: ruby, callcc

I'm having a hard time figuring out why `Enumerable#take` never terminates given my enumerator:

```
require 'continuation'

fib = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
  c, x, y = callcc {|cc| [cc, 0, 1]}
  yielder << x
  c.call c, y, x+y
end

# this works as I'd suspect
1.upto(10) do
  puts fib.next
end

# this works as I'd suspect
fib.take(1)

# this never terminates :(
fib.take(10)
```

From taking a quick glance at [enum.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/enum.c), it looks like the counter in [args[1]](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/enum.c#L2037) is probably getting reset to the initial length requested, causing the iteration to never terminate at line [2019](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/enum.c#L2019). My understanding is that the stack should be restored when the enumerator's internal fiber yields (at `yielder << x`), and thus my `c.call ...` shouldn't be a problem (despite it temporarily setting `args[1]` back to the original length argument)... but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Can anyone explain why `fib.take(n)` never terminates for some n > 1? Is there something fundamental about how `callcc` works that I'm probably missing here?

**Note:** This is on Ruby 1.9.3. And yes, I realize my use of `callcc` is sort of silly :).

Comment: Ruby bugs go to bugs.ruby-lang.com

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I wasn't positive this was a bug, or just me misunderstanding something. I'll open a ticket and see what the devs say.